# 500 error when attempting to view Stackoverflow Careers 2.0 profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

### Request URLs with redirects

**Public page:** http://careers.stackoverflow.com/sobes

- 302 -> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fsobes
- 500

**Logged in:** http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv

- 302 -> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/206116
- 302 -> http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Fcv%2Fedit%2F206116
- 500

Comment: Works for me...

Comment: "Oops! Something Bad Happened"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry about that - try again please, it should be fixed.

Comment: That was quick! What happened there?

Comment: Some pointer decided they'd rather be null.

Comment: Oh the dreaded "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error... no programmer can escape it apparently!

Comment: And that is why it is a bad idea to allow `null` as reference. (If I'd design a language, I'd not allow that, except if it is declared with a `?` - fail early)

Comment: is it happening here too? http://stackoverflow.com/cv/eduardo