# Cannot view my profile (logged in or not)

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I am getting an error screen when trying to view my profile. This happens whether I am logged in or not. I've tried this in IE 11 and Google Chrome 33.x

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jeffyates

Comment: Did you try Private/Incognito mode? Oh, well, I get error too! You broke careers... ;)

Comment: Indeed, there is a server error there. As the error page states: The team has already been notified.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I can reproduce the (server) error, it doesn't matter if I am logged in or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good morning/afternoon/evening everyone and welcome to the (hopefully last) installment of **[Return of the NULL Pointer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215309)**.

Please try again, the issue should be fixed.

Comment: You should write a book "The null that hates me". ;)

Comment: I will write this book if your comment gets at least 100 upvotes. :)

Comment: Challenge accepted! :)

Comment: @Max: Great! Thanks for all you do.

Comment: @Max [cough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216697/152859) :)

Comment: :-( yeah saw it, thanks!

Comment: @Max 31 upvotes and counting... maybe you shouldn't have posted that comment ;)