# Can't see or edit my profile on Careers 2.0

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

For the past two days I have not been able to access my profile on Careers 2.0. Every time I try to get to my profile (i.e. by clicking the "my profile" button in the top menu) I get this page:

[image: error page]

Comment: Most likely a leftover from [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215309/152859).

Comment: So it's working for me, but I did find an exception error from when you tried to access your profile. Not being a dev, it's gibberish to me so I'll get someone to look into it Monday morning. If it makes you feel better you're not the only one with the issue. Also, looks like you're on OSX Mavericks and Chrome v32? Does it happen in other browsers?

Comment: I'm actually on Windows 7 (if you're tracking my User Agent string it should contain "Windows NT"). Also, I'm getting the exact same error page on Firefox v26 and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: @Juice only one of the web servers was affected, that's why you didn't get a repro.

Answer (score 2):

Should be fixed for now - could someone confirm who has been affected?

We'll investigate in more detail next week why this keeps coming back.

Comment: Yes it is fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for confirming!