# Can't edit my Careers profile

Tags: support, jobs

I just signed up on Careers but don't appear to have a profile, or at least I can't edit anything.

- When I click *my profile*, I see the *about your profile* view, so this is similar to [Can't see or edit my profile on Careers 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216697) but not exactly the same.
- http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/54180 returns a 404 for me.

I tried clearing caches too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you receive an invite from us? Even though anyone can create an account on Careers, you have to be invited to create a profile. Go here, http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one, to see if you auto qualify. If you don't, let me know and I'll hook you up.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! That was a little confusing.. You can sign up and create a profile but you can't edit it unless you.. get invited.. but you're already signed up. It's not really mentioned explicitly, or at least I couldn't find it.